# What would using grepl(“\\|”, terms) find in R?

Tags: r, model

So I'm sifting through an R code that is finding submodels within linear mixed models. This is the first part of the code for the function:

```
findsubmodel.lmer = function(full) {

resp = as.character(full)[2]

tms = attributes(terms(full))$term.labels

fr = grepl("\\|", tms)
```

So `"full"` is talking about your full model. I understand what the `grepl` function does in general, but what would finding matches to `"\\|"` in the term labels be doing?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's just see what this does on an example:

```
full <- y~x+(1|x)
resp = as.character(full)[2]
resp
## [1] "y"
tms = attributes(terms(full))$term.labels
tms
## [1] "x"     "1 | x"
fr = grepl("\\|", tms)
fr
## [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

So the practical point is that it identifies terms containing `|` (which will be random-effects terms in the `lme4` syntax).  What does `\\|` mean? We're looking for `|`, but in regular-expression syntax that has a special meaning, so we need to [escape](https://xkcd.com/234/) it (tell R to look for a literal `|` character).  To do that, we have to put a backslash `\` in front of it - but R also uses `\` to escape special characters in strings, so we need to tell R we *really mean* backslash, hence we add another backslash.

You might also be interested in `?lme4::findbars` ...